# Install Django Application so It's Available on Python Path

Tags: python, django

I have a django application structured like this...

```
app_foo
  __init__.py
  urls.py
  views.py
  models.py
  bar_app
    __init__.py
    ...
  bar_app...
```

By using distutils, I can get the application to install into the python path under the "app_foo" module name.

However, any of the code inside of the "bar_app" python files which refers to things inside the django app relatively does not work when executed from the python path.  For example,

```
from bar_app.views import stuff
```

I know that I can go through the app and change all the references to be absolute.  For example,

```
from app_foo.bar_app.views import stuff
```

My question:

Is there anyway I can get all of the apps inside "app_foo" to also be on the python path?

Conceptually this would be similar to saying from app_foo import * for the entire path.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
from .bar_app.views import stuff
```

http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

Comment: this is definitely better than specifying app name.  i'll do this if there's not a way to get them all on the path